# $H(e^{j\omega})$ represented with a limited no of samples

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform

I have a low pass filter defined as:

$$ H_{lp}(e^{j\omega})=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&1 &|\omega|>\omega_c \\
&0 &\omega_c<|\omega|<\pi
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

and the corresponding sequence in the discrete-time domain is

$$h[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\omega_c}_{-\omega_c}e^{j\omega n}d\omega=\frac{\sin(\omega_cn)}{\pi n}$$

The discrete time-domain signal $h[n]$ has infinite samples.

If we consider only a finite amount of samples:

$$H_M(e^{j\omega})=\sum^{M}_{n=-M}\frac{\sin(\omega_c n)}{\pi n}e^{-j\omega n}$$

And then the book says

$H_M(e^{j\omega})$ can also be represented as:

$$H_M(e^{j\omega})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\omega_c}_{-\omega_c} \frac{\sin[(2M+1)\frac{(\omega-\theta)}{2}]}{\sin[\frac{(\omega-\theta)}{2}]} d\theta$$

How was this expression evaluated?

This is an example from Oppenheim Discrete-Time Signal Processing book

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The first thing I'd try (without guarantee of success) is the property of the Fourier transform where $\mathcal F \left \lbrace h[n] g[n] \right \rbrace$ = $\mathcal F  \left \lbrace h[n] \right \rbrace \star \mathcal F  \left \lbrace g[n] \right \rbrace$.

Comment: You need to learn about the various windows and what effect their application in the discrete-time domain has in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

1. figure out the frequency response $W(e^{j\omega})$ of a symmetric rectangular window $w[n]$ of length $2M+1$
2. note that the truncated impulse response is $h_M[n]=h[n]w[n]$
3. from the previous equation, note that the frequency response $H_M(e^{j\omega})$ can be written as the convolution of $W(e^{j\omega})$ with a rectangle. This results in the representation given in your question.

Comment: you mean to say .... to say treat this like the signal in the time domain only multiplied by a rectangular pulse of length 2M+1...and since it is multiplied in time domain...it is convolved in frequency domain...